# symfony2 : how to redirect from a custom event listener

Tags: php, symfony, events, redirect, event-listener

I have built a custom event listener, listening to a custom event in symfony2.

This event does not have the setResponse method nor does it have access to the request so I am struggling to perform a redirect from my event listener.

What would be the way we could do that ? Should I add something in my event to make it able to modify the response ? Is there a way to just perform the redirect directly in the listener ?

Thanks !

Comment: What sort of custom event and what emits the event?  Your listener could return a response and then whatever emits the event (if it is a controller) could pass it on?  Or have your listener toss an exception and have an exception listener do the redirect.

Comment: So my event is actually empty (no method in the class), I just need to trigger it when the user changes a dropdown (it allows a user to act on behalf of another user). I want my listener to listen to security.interactive_login and to this custom event to perform some operations and a redirection (no exception is thrown).
My listener could send a response which I could pass on in the controller triggering the custom event, but how to pass it on to what's triggering the security.interactive_login event then ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so for the record, I went for a solution involving a custom login handler and a separate event listener, both taking as a controller argument a class where I put my logic and return a value indicating if the direction should happen or not. This value is handled by the handler which performs the redirect, or used by the eventListener to modify the event which is then read by the controller which performs the redirect.

As for how to redirect from within the event listener, I heard it's bad practice.

So for the eventlistener:

In my controller :

```
            $event = new PortfolioChangeEvent();
            $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(FoodMeUpEvents::PORFOLIO_CHANGE, $event);
            if ($event->getRedirect()) return $this->redirectToRoute('cms', array('dir' => 'general', 'page' => 'foodmeup_premium'));
```

and in my eventlistener :

```
public function onPortfolioUserChange(PortfolioChangeEvent $event)
{
      $event->setRedirect(true);
}
```

and my event :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class PortfolioChangeEvent extends Event
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="bool")
     */
    private $redirect = false;

    public function getRedirect()
    {
        return $this->redirect;
    }

    public function setRedirect($redirect)
    {
        $this->redirect = $redirect;

        return $this;
    }
}
```